# Request goes into Keycloak even if configured as permitAll

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, keycloak

I have below `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which is to authenticate using `KeyCloak` if it doesn't have specific path's in the URL. In my case it's except `"/payment/**"` everything should be bypassed. Only `"/payment/**"`should be authenticated using `KeyCloak`.

```
@Bean
@Override
@Primary
public KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {

    KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            authenticationManagerBean()
            , new RequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/payment/**"))
    );

    filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
    return filter;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.csrf().disable().cors().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/payment/**").authenticated();
    http.headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Content-Security-Policy", "script-src 'self'"));
}
```

Actual: If I have hit @GET request `/public/**` with Bearer Token(only in the case of Bearer Toke as I have other request which has bearer token in it), it gives me following error

> Error: o.k.a.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier      : Didn't find publicKey for kid: RVH0bfDX6ZPkFkVBvCl5zV2BVPGMtvbhenA6dh9IDxs

Excepted: It should not invoke `KeyCloak` at all as request is other than `/payment/**`

Tried:  All the possible ways to negate(`/payment/**`) or only accept(`/payment/**`) in request filter. Though if it sees Authorization header it goes into KeyCloak for any request or path.

StackTrace:

```
2021-03-30 15:56:37.298 DEBUG 67688 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:9090/api/public/orders/94
2021-03-30 15:56:37.299 DEBUG 67688 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:9090/api/public/orders/94
2021-03-30 15:56:37.309 DEBUG 67688 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Found [1] values in authorization header, selecting the first value for Bearer.
2021-03-30 15:56:37.309 DEBUG 67688 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Verifying access_token
2021-03-30 15:56:37.318 DEBUG 67688 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Resolving URLs from https://keycloak-dev.deviceapi.com/auth/realms/admin/.well-known/openid-configuration
2021-03-30 15:56:38.018  INFO 67688 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment   : Loaded URLs from https://keycloak-dev.deviceapi.com/auth/realms/admin/.well-known/openid-configuration
2021-03-30 15:56:38.128 DEBUG 67688 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.k.a.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator       : Realm public keys successfully retrieved for client DEVICE-PROJECT-EVENT. New kids: [yUDSD-1WHU4B07pkSQZTfA7_XPGu4jeUdAZKPTBJT98]
2021-03-30 15:56:38.128 ERROR 67688 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.k.a.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier      : Didn't find publicKey for kid: RVH0bfDX6ZPkFkVBvCl5zV2BVPGMtvbhenA6dh9IDxs
2021-03-30 15:56:38.128 DEBUG 67688 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Failed to verify token
2021-03-30 15:56:38.130 DEBUG 67688 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : Bearer FAILED
```

Why KeyCloak fetches value from Authorization Header as the request should be bypassed as it's other than `/payment/**`?

> Found [1] values in authorization header, selecting the first value for Bearer.

Findings:

> Request goes under
> `org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator.authenticate(...)`
> Though it shouldn't, as request is from `/public/**`(With Authorization Header) and not `/payment/**`

Is there a way one can make such request in KeyCloak configuration which can accept only (`/payment/**`) with Authorization Token and ignores the rest?

Comment: could you add full stack trace?

Comment: why do you use NegatedRequestMatcher? AbstractAuthenticationProcessing filter checkL if matcher return true than try to authenticate. so, with your matcher it looks like try to authenticate every request except /payment/**

Comment: @ZhenyaM I have added a full stack trace in SO. Moreover I have changed the logic from negate to request matcher. Though as per stacktrace, if request has Authorization Header it goes into KeyCloak.

Comment: try to change order `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/payment/**").authenticated().anyRequest().permitAll();`

Comment: @ZhenyaM I have already tried to change the order you have mentioned above. I have tried to intercept the request in `KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver` and setting the request. 

Do you have any idea, how to remove the Authorization header and set it once again, once it passes through KeyCloak?

Comment: @ZhenyaM I have already tried to change the order you have mentioned above. But still,

it goes under org.keycloak.adapters.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator in authenticate(HttpFacade exchange) and as the request has Authorization Header. It tries to authenticate but it shouldn't as the request is except "/payment/**"

Do you have any idea, Why it goes to authenticate?

Comment: why there is `super.configure(http);` added to the overriden method ? It add default behaviour to httpSecurity.. Can you try removing it ?

Comment: @hiren I did try removing `super.configure(http);`, though the issue persists.